# how to change featured title name in opencart 3

Tags: opencart-3

How to change featured product title name in home page of opencart 3.I want to add some products with other title in home page.like given screenshot-[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQBED.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the module name on the featured products you need to change controller, template files from both sides of the store (i.e. from the front end and backend).

Instead, you can use the [extension](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/download&member_token=7tNQvU1d9RMCGvHwQyJOyGzIy7i0ISOl&extension_id=30994&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=49) to get desired.

Hope this helps you

Comment: what happened sir.

Answer (score 0):

Steps

1. Go to your `project folder`.
2. Go to `catalog -> language -> en-gb -> extension -> module`
3. Inside the `module` you will get `featured.php`
4. Go to `featured.php` file and
5. Edit `$_['heading_title'] = 'Feature Products';`
6. `Feature Products` name can changed according to your wish.
7. You are done.

Thanks.